# Keep chrome open while a game is on fullscreen

Tags: windows

Maybe this question doesn't belong here but I didn't know where else to ask. Is it possible to have chrome open and overlap another fullscreen game. For example I am on gta 5 and at the right top corner there is a chrome tab pinned there. Is this possible ?

Here is an edited photo of what I am trying to achieve. [Link](https://ibb.co/vm9w8XW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something that [`AutoHotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can do.

Try this script to toggle the `AlwaysOnTop` state of your chrome window before fullscreening your app:

```
;Alt+T = Toggle AlwaysOnTop state of the active window
!t::WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle, A
```

[Source from the AHK forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94627-button-for-always-on-top/?p=596273)

If you want to change `Alt+T` (`!t`) to be a different hotkey, take a look at the [`Hotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) section in the AHK documentation.